# How to record a whatsapp voice call, like mobile sims call recording?

Tags: android

I'm developing an call recorder application  and i want to also record whatsapp voice calls how to record? im using Telephony Phone manager for incoming and outgoing call and also using system Audio Source MIC so anyone can tell me how to whatsapp voice call recordings?

Comment: please guide me

Comment: Hi Xeeshan Sami, Are you able to solve the above problem? How you implemented a solution to handle this case?

Comment: @chetanmekha i cant resolve it brother

Comment: Thanks for the reply, we remove this feature as due to unavailability of access